# How can a 1 byte int conversion of a QByteArray fail?

Tags: qt

So here is the thing, I'm receiving 1 byte from Bluetooth transmission. When using QDebug I get this message:

```
The array with error has "\x06"
```

The line that fails is this:

```
    bool ok = true;
    int v = value.toInt(&ok,0);
```

Because `ok` has `false`. But I'm trying to wrap my head around the fact that, How can the conversion fail in the first place if the data represented in that byte (as a sequence of zeros and ones) will always have a valid integer representation. (one byte can always be represented as a int between -127 and 128). So I'm left with the question, how can the conversion fail?

Reading the documentation does not provide many clues as it does not say how the byte array will be interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QByteArray::toInt` converts a string representation in the default C locale to an integer. That means to successfully convert the value in your example, your byte  array must contain the string `"0x06"`, which consists of 4 bytes.

To convert a single byte to an int, just extract it:

```
int i = value[0];
```

Type promotion will widen the char to an int

Comment: Ok. It does't contain that string. It simply prints the binary representation of 6 that way because that is the way QDebug prints it.